# How to call a C++ class method, which is given as a parameter?

Tags: c++, pointers, methods, parameters, pointer-to-member

I'm trying to pass a method as a parameter to other method.

`Magner.h`:

```
Class Manager{
public:
 timeCount(void (Manger::*function)(void));
void passedFuction();
}
```

In `Manager.cpp`, I'm trying to call `timeCount` by

```
timeCount(&Manager::passedFuction());
```

TimeCount Body:

```
void Manager::timeCount(void(Manager::*function)(void))
{
    std::cout << "It works";
    (*function)(); // here is error
}
```

ViusalStudio says:

```
void*Manager::*function)() operand of '*' must be a pointer
```

How should i correct it?
The example i was learing by was : http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/6596/

Comment: The example you are learning from predates C++11.  It isn't the way I'd do it in Modern C++ — I'd use `std::function` and lambdas.  Also, you are not doing what the example is demonstrating.

Comment: Required reading: [C++ FAQ - Pointers to member functions](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A pointer-to-member-function (pmf) is not a pointer.  Let me repeat that:

### A pointer-to-member-function is *not* a pointer.

To call a pmf, you have to provide it with the object you want to call it on.  You probably want:

```
    (this->*function)();
```

If you had another object `obj` of the right type, you could also use:

```
    (obj.*function)();
```

Comment: Ok. Just tried and it works. 

does pmf means parameter fuction?

Comment: No, "Pointer to Member Function".  I'll edit the post to clarify.

Comment: @anatolyg : I think I do, yes.  Most of the difficulty with pmf's is associated with the misleading name.

Answer (score 4):

The `void (Manger::*function)(void)` syntax is for member functions of `Manager` class, which cannot be used with functions *outside* the `Manager` class.

To fix this shortcoming, pass `std::function<void(void)>` instead, which would let you invoke itself using the regular function invocation syntax:

```
void Manager::timeCount(std::function<void(void)> f) {
    std::cout << "It works";
    f();
}
```

Here is a complete demo of how to call `timeCount` with member and non-member functions:

```
struct Manager {
    string name;
    void timeCount(std::function<void(void)> f) {
        std::cout << "This is " << name << " manager" << endl;
        f();
    }
};

void foo() {
    cout << "I'm foo" << endl;
}

struct Test {
    int x;
    void bar() {
        cout << "I'm bar " << x << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Manager mgr {"time"};
    mgr.timeCount(foo);
    Test tst = {234};
    mgr.timeCount(std::bind( &Test::bar, tst));
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/pTfqFy)

Comment: How would you call `timeCount` in this case?

Comment: @MartinBonner I added a running demo, please take a look.

Answer (score 2):

Since c++17, we have [`std::invoke`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke):

```
std::invoke(function, this);
```

or

```
std::invoke(function, *this);
```

are both ok. Minimal demo:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
class Manager
{
public:
    void timeCount(void (Manager::*function)(void));
    void passedFuction()
    {
        std::cout << "call passedFunction\n";
    }
};

void Manager::timeCount(void (Manager::*function)(void))
{
    std::cout << "It works\n";
    std::invoke(function, *this);
    //    (*function)(); // here is error
}

int main()
{
    Manager a;
    a.timeCount(&Manager::passedFuction);
}
```

> It works
>
> call passedFunction

[**`live demo`**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/FeLOS2RutL9ZiyIa)